# How to find the average bucket length in a hash map?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am doing a class assignment and it asks us to create a HashMap and then fill it with random values, first without the dynamic resizing and then with the dynamic resizing in order to see the speed difference smaller bucket sizes makes in storing values.

In order to do this it asks me to create a method that finds the shortest bucket length, the average bucket length, and the longest bucket length in the HashMap.

This is where I am running into problems as when I try and get the lengths of the buckets it always returns zero. I'm not sure where my problem lies as my code logically makes sense to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code for my HashMap and my Main program that is calling it.

```
public class MyHashMap<K, V> {
    private LinkedList<KVP <K, V>>[] bucket;
    private int M = 5;
    private int size = 0;


    public MyHashMap(int M){
        this.bucket = (LinkedList<KVP<K, V>>[]) new LinkedList[M];
        for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
            bucket[i] = new LinkedList<KVP<K, V>>();
        }
    }
    public MyHashMap(){
        this.bucket = (LinkedList<KVP<K, V>>[]) new LinkedList[M];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            bucket[i] = new LinkedList<KVP<K, V>>();
        }
    }

    public int getBucketNumber(K key){
        return Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % this.bucket.length;
    }
    public void put(K key, V value){
        //resize();
        size++;
        int b = getBucketNumber(key);
        for(KVP<K, V> pair : this.bucket[b]){
            if(pair.key.equals(key)){
                pair.value = value;
                return;
            }
        }
        KVP<K, V> pair = new KVP<>(key, value);
        this.bucket[b].add(pair);
    }
    public int size(){
        return this.bucket.length;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return size == 0;
    }
    public void resize(){
      if(size > size() * 2){
          LinkedList<KVP <K, V>>[] newHash = (LinkedList<KVP<K, V>>[]) new LinkedList[2 * size()];
          for(int i = 0; i < newHash.length; i++){
              newHash[i] = new LinkedList<KVP <K, V>>();
          }
          for(LinkedList<KVP<K, V>> map: this.bucket){
              for(KVP<K, V> pair: map){
                  int newHashCode = Math.abs(pair.key.hashCode()) % newHash.length;
                  newHash[newHashCode].add(pair);
              }
          }
          this.bucket = newHash;
      }     
    }

    public void delete(K key){
        int b = getBucketNumber(key);
        for(KVP<K, V> pair : this.bucket[b]){
            if(pair.key.equals(key)){
                key = null;
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean containsKey(K key){
        int b = getBucketNumber(key);
        boolean t = false;
        for(KVP<K, V> pair : this.bucket[b]){
            if(pair.key.equals(key)){
                t = true;
            }else{
                t = false;
            }
        }
            return t;
    }
    public V get(K key){
        int b = getBucketNumber(key);
        for(KVP<K, V> pair : this.bucket[b]){
            if(pair.key.equals(key)){
                return pair.value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public int Avg(){
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < bucket.length; i++){
            j += bucket[i].size();
        }
        return j/bucket.length;
    }

}

public class hwMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int N = (int) Math.pow(10, 3);
        MyHashMap<Integer, Integer> store = new MyHashMap<>();      
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){

            store.put((int) Math.random(), 1);
            }
        System.out.print(store.Avg());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: int / int -> int, so 1 / 2 = 0.

Comment: One improvement not related to question : You can resize the bucket from the delete also as this will reduce the space and deallocate extra spaces

Answer (score 1):

Because according to `Math.random()`:

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to
>   0.0 and less than 1.0.

Since the number is always less than 1.0, when you do this:

```
(int) Math.random()
```

This always returns 0 (zero).

**Solution:**

If you have a range of the random numbers and a minimum value, use this:

```
(int) (Math.random() * range) + minimum
```

For example: you want to take random numbers from 1 to 100.

```
(int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1
```

Comment: The actual values would not affect the average number of Key Value Pairs per bucket even if they are less than 1 as the keys are only being used to calculate a hashcode before being sorted into buckets. Well i mean they do but since they are random it shouldn't noticeably affect the average per bucket.

Comment: For all of the `put`, the value of `key` will be 0. Won't be this a problem??

Comment: I understand what you mean now, but when I add the minimum and range now it returns a value of 20 every time so I'm not sure that was the issue.

Comment: What are the values of range and minimum?

Comment: I set the range at 100 and the minimum at 1 like you had it. Additionally I used another suggestion and changed the average method calculations to  produce doubles instead of integers. I'm not sure if these two things are adversely affecting each other.